# Please explain how this XNOR gate works

Tags: logic-gates

[image][image]

As S1 is 1 (5 V) and S2 is 0 (0 V) then D1 is conducting, D3 and D4 are reverse biased, and D2 is conducting. Q1 is switched over and shuts the output to 0 V via D2 and S2, etc. All states. Could someone will explain the rest?

The first pattern is good and the second pattern is bad.

Comment: How is S1 switching 5V? It is connected to ground.

Comment: That looks like a diode rectifier.

Comment: In the second drawing, both switches conect to Ground in both positions - please correct your drawing.

Comment: This is the XNOR gate it does with diodes and the second drawing is wrong

Comment: @Artur3524 - Hi, I notice that you tried to say "thank you" in an answer. If your question has been solved, please consider "accepting" (click the "green tick") the answer which most helped you to solve the problem. (You don't yet have enough points to upvote answers.) If your problem is *not* yet solved, and you were just saying thanks to be polite, you can comment on an answer to request clarification etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the first circuit, for the transistor to turn on, at least one of the switches must be 'off' (GND) while the other 'on' (5V) to provide a current path though the transistor base-emitter junction.

The second circuit doesn't have any 5V path to the transistor base (the collector doesn't count), so the transistor never turns on.

Try them both here: [Falstad Simulation of XNOR Gate](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgA3EPKzFbqsUJQRNKkiqToCNgHdwGYXwEhlkNgBNVePAuHZswsItXgAcggytNIA0vzbdaJyA0MAZgEMArgBsALjZ2qhj8KDohYa4ePgE24U5itoaqSfxuXn6B8sHKNDyRUHKOeqlUxsLq-rT5pfnlJuW20LiQ2ARgeGSEhsQINMysza0oxAZWxCjGKAjYgxBgcNGZcQBOtAVCG%20WEkshwxfXgk9uF6vKbwkdb6gDKZaXOpU1evgDODCIobPcoaWkOP57CCvD5fYpPGZGExQoryJ5gE4VY78c6lRH8ZGwtFYhDQpShIrrdo0Oq1ZHleBsQy6I5gXYUcLgBmSCGAv7gGiklActEIhlgLnM1nyQXcjli4Vwzmk%20lUS5FGmnEmM3QqkV1ArImg3Yra%20majVPGgG-WVNm0rUmI5ogrYNDKh1oo4mq4FHXm9ZHe1Ub14UmUg7VLm0pYupZNJgYaBkUiEFDYDD4IT5DDMcgsWA80Z2RYYfJcsCDTFLDKxbJ1Lbu3VcavCO1O0TiERSGQAcxUygKCRbbA7dZUCDAqOlPaBD3HaOCyKVFOKKpnhF0c5yKXHSsn86XD1njXna4cuUJfIiWIiTxPTkJY6Sl9oWx7NEIAYhETEvDf9ulwTo-B-upybcn1JJV32-FJgNsIDn2-f1aCWUCI33K4EKApD4TfGDx0g9RiTgsCQ3g4EqV%20JJIONGCXk8d5Pl4H4HjA40I3AEBQVo1RX1DXgyPQ5Iri2F1dS0R8YJ-LDlnLIIIIfN8HwkrIpKuL9H2U%20S4mEt8EIgpZMQsKx2CAA)

[image]

I've redrawn the diodes to make clearer how the currents flow, and to show that the diode + switch combos are identical.

Answer (score 0):

If one of the switches is high, and the other low, there's a path for current to flow around the circuit through the transistor base. E.g. in the first image, S1 is high and S2 low, so current flows from the positive side of the voltage source through S1, D1, the transistor base, D2 back to the negative side of the voltage source.

[image]

If the switches are flipped, it would flow through D4 and D3 instead. Similarly, the collector current also reaches ground through either D2 or D3.

If both switches are low, or both are high, the ends of the loop passing through the transistor base are connected to the same point, either ground or the positive voltage. Either way, there is no voltage difference around the loop, and no current.

[Similar circuit simplified in the Falstad simulator.](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgAZcQqsH8MCm5VeIAGYBDADYBnBtUidhIFAkIChq9aMmz5SRQBMVa5bhor8KkIYaSArlIAubY2jyWPW5UNsPnbADuJurefFTeisFh-OHKUSDmnonYoVYJ7omQFmDEQkkJufnZ4HnJhWWZVemuyVWm3r52Eo4ubg2mSVU2za1sfPmpWRaZXT3+TkxSDMYQIlCw7ABOKWke2EMFyHBsQA)